# "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required." error when installing machine module

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

```
PS C:\Users\janri\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code Project\Smart Locker System Pico> pip install machine
Collecting machine
  Downloading machine-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pycrypto (from machine)
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 446.2/446.2 kB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pycrypto (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How to solve this error? I want to program a Raspberry Pi Pico W with Visual Studio Code and installed MicroPico extension.

Comment: Have you seen `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` in the error message?

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is related package PyCrypto cannot be installed. This module does not provide a Windows version.